# How do I use two .siblings with the same input type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get "The walking dead" also but it only gets the first hidden. Can i put a class on .this or how should I do?

```
$(".articel input[type='button']").click(function(){                    
        var price = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").attr("value");
        var quantity =  $(this).siblings("input[type='number']").attr("value");
        var name = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").attr("value");
        var ul = document.getElementById("buylist"); 
        var prod = name + " x " + quantity + " " + price + "$";

        var el = document.createElement("li"); 
        el.innerHTML = prod; 
        ul.appendChild(el);

<form class="articel">
        Quantity: <input type="number" style="width:25px;"><br>
        Add to cart: <input type="button" class="btn">
        <input type="hidden" value="30">
        <input type="hidden" value="The walking dead">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional way to identify form fields is by the `name` property.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="The walking dead">
```

jQuery:

```
var name = $(this).siblings('input[name=title]').val();
```

Your current selector, `siblings("input[type='hidden']")`, selects *all* hidden field siblings, but since you have no way to discern them, `attr` will always just yield the value of the first match.

You could also have iterated over your collection of elements, or accessed them by index `siblings('input[type=hidden]:eq(1)')` or `siblings('input[type=hidden]').eq(1)`, for instance, but it is a poor design that will break your code if you add another hidden field for something else. You really should prefer to name your elements so that you can access them in a meaningful way and know your data. That way you'll be free to move around and modify your markup according to new requirements, without breaking your script.

By the way, I'm using `.val()` above, which is shorthand for `.attr('value')`.

Comment: Ah, did see that you used .val insted of .attr('value'). Thanks for the extra info.

Comment: Can I ask another question while im here...? just if you know an easy way of making the quantity numbers input only accept whole numbers and not decimals?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use special selectors, e.g. `:first` and `:last`:

```
var price = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']:first").attr("value");
var name = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']:last").attr("value");
```

However, you always can set a class name to the elements:

```
<input type="hidden" class="price" value="30">
<input type="hidden" class="name" value="The walking dead">

var price = $(this).siblings(".price").attr("value");
var name = $(this).siblings(".name").attr("value");
```

Comment: Thanks, I used Davids answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would add an class name to your hidden inputs (price, name). This way the html source code is more readable and also the js code will be more readable.